# Hibernate @NotNull (only if another property isn't null?)

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, orm

I have some sections in a form which if ticked yes, its sub sections become mandatory.

How Can I do this?

```
@NotNullIfOtherPropertyNotNull(PropertyName='OtherProperty')
private myProperty;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy to do as a type level constraint.  You just create something like

```
@CascadingNotNull(ifNotNull="otherProperty", thenAlsoNotNull="myProperty")
```

If you put that on the class, then in your ConstraintHandler you can use whatever flavour of reflect/bean library you like to get the two properties and do the check.

Comment: so you mean create a custom validator constraint class? then in the isValid override() write my logic?

Comment: Yes, you would create a Constraint and a ConstraintValidator that interprets it.